# how to use try and except to prevent a for-loop from stopping

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a bunch of samples that are dictionaries and some of the values are in lists. I would like to retrieve information from the lists but sometimes the list is empty in some of the keys. What I am trying to do is retrieve certain values. I would like to make a statement that if the list is empty then retrieve a value from a different key.

I made an if-elif statement but can't get it to work. I tried to code that if the list==None then do something elif do something else. It seems like None doesn't work though.

I put an example of what I am trying to do below.

```
sample_1 = {'description' : {'captions': [],
                           'tags': ['person',
                                   'cat']}}
sample_2 = {'description' : {'captions': ['NOT an empty list'],
                           'tags': ['person',
                                   'cat']}}


# if captions list is empty then print first item in 'tags' list.
# else if the 'captions' list has an item then print that item 
if sample_here['captions']==None in sample_here:
    result = sample_here['description']['tags'][0]
elif 'captions' in sample_here:
    result = sample_here['description']['captions'][0]
```

Comment: what is `sample_here['captions']==None in sample_here`?

Comment: What is `sample_here`? And what is `if sample_here['captions']==None in sample_here:` supposed to test?

Comment: When the list is empty in the function there is no information in it that I am interested in so I would like to retrieve values from the 'tags' key. However, if there is information in the 'captions' list I would like to just have the value in that 'captions' list.  Sample_here is just where you can plug in the 2 samples I made above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python you normally try to do something and then handle the exception thrown, if any. In your case I'd first try to read from the list and catch the thrown exception, like this:

```
try:
    result = sample_here['description']['captions'][0]        
except IndexError:
    result = sample_here['description']['tags'][0]
```

If the `try` block fails you execute the `except` block.

Comment: maybe opposite direction, vice versa?

Comment: @U9-Forward, sorry, I didn't get that, what do you mean?

Comment: So i mean, `result = sample_here['description']['captions'][0]`  first, and `result = sample_here['description']['tags'][0]` second

Comment: Right, I missed that! Thanks!

Comment: So, if I get errors I can just bypass them by doing except and then that particular error? Good to know.

Comment: @zipline86 yes, it's said that in python it's [Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission (EAFP)](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html)

Comment: This try except is great. I've been using it to get past lots of errors so I can keep continueing and then I debug later.

Answer (score 3):

An empty list [] is not equal to None.

```
sample_1 = {'description' : {'captions': [],
                           'tags': ['person',
                                   'cat']}}
sample_2 = {'description' : {'captions': ['NOT an empty list'],
                           'tags': ['person',
                                   'cat']}}
def get_captions(sample_here):
    # thanks to bruno desthuilliers's correction. [] has a bool value False
    if not sample_here['description']['captions']:
        result = sample_here['description']['tags'][0]
    else:
        result = sample_here['description']['captions'][0]
    return result

print(get_captions(sample_1))
print(get_captions(sample_2))
```

This outputs:

```
person
NOT an empty list
```

Comment: An empty list has a false value in a boolean context so the pythonic way to test against an empty list is `if not sample_here['description']['captions']`

Comment: Thank you, Bruno. Definitely want to code in a pythonic way. Code has been revised as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a pseudo code.

So try:

```
if not sample['captions']:
    result = sample['description']['tags'][0]
else:
    result = sample['description']['captions'][0]
```

Even though I don't know what `sample_here` is.

Or do a def:

```
def f(sample):
    if not sample['description']['captions']:
        result = sample['description']['tags'][0]
    else:
        result = sample['description']['captions'][0]
    return result
```

Then can do:

```
print(f(sample1))
```

Or:

```
print(f(sample2))
```

Then get your desired output

Comment: It's not sudo it's pseudo. and instead of `if not sample_here['captions']` do `if not sample_here['description']['captions']`

Comment: @MaorRefaeli Yeah

Comment: I took out sample_here since I'm not making too much sense.

Comment: @zipline86 Now?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is basically to check whether the  list is empty or no,

Which can simply be achieved in a pythonic way wiz:

```
 if not a: 
     print("a is empty")
```

Hope it helps.